# Next auth with SpringBoot as resource server

Tags: spring-boot, next.js, spring-security, next-auth

I have a NextJS app with NextAuth setup as my authentication service.

My backend is in Springboot 3.0.3.

I am trying to set up the oauth2 resource server in spring-boot to be able to decode the JWT token from NextAuth but I cannot find any valid issuer-URI in order to be able to have role-based entry points in my API.

Is it possible to use this stack and have secured backend endpoints?

Here is the configuration in springboot:
application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: '@project.name@'
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:3000/api/auth // What should I put here?
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer((server) -> server
                        .jwt()
                        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())
                );

        return http.build();
    }
```

[...next-auth].ts

```
export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
}
```

Comment: the adress you place in your config i used to verify that the JWT contains the same `iss`claim. So simplest for you would to take an issued JWT, check what it contains using for example https://jwt.io/ and read whats in the `iss`claim and then stick that in your yaml. But remember, you either use yaml config to setup resource server OR you use a custom security configuration. You can't use both. here is a demo application https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. The thing is that the jwt.io says that is not a valid json to deserialize.

Comment: then thats your problem right there